# Taxonomy terms won't arrange themselves by ID but will work alphabetically instead

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

I added a large number of taxonomy terms in the order I want. Their term IDs reflect they are added in the correct order. However, everywhere they are displayed alphabetically. Particularly, inside a hierarchical select widget they are displayed alphabetically - when I see their IDs (856, 847, 843 - not a correct numeric order but correct alphabetic A, B, C) they check out fine so they were added properly. How can I control this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which you enter the taxonomy terms is not important to how they are displayed. Drupal defaults to alphabetic ordering, but you can adjust this order manually.

Go to Content management > Taxonomy > Your vocabulary: List terms (via `admin/content/taxonomy/list`) and reorder the terms by dragging the handle on the left. This is also the order Hierarchical Select uses.

You can also try out [Taxonomy Manager](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) to see if this provides you with a better interface for reordering large numbers of terms.

Comment: `Taxonomy Manager` also displays everything alphabetically :( I did not know that the order of entry is totally unimportant. Is there a core SQL command you know of, that I can change so Drupal will order by the `tid`s instead of by alphabet? There are hundreds of terms in this taxonomy, and I haven't seen re-ordering features in `Taxonomy Manager`...

Comment: Yes, Taxonomy Manager is just an alternative interface, it doesn't have this specific feature.  The table term_data of your database contains tid and weight columns, you'd have to set the weight of your terms with a SQL query. I'm not sure if there are specific requirements for values in the weight column though, or what the best way to do this is.

Comment: That actually sounds great! I believe setting `weight = tid` might solve the problem...

Answer (score 1):

What version of Drupal? There's a module for D6 called TagOrder that'll probably do what you want. If you're in D7 you may need to see if there's a port of it or an equivalent: http://drupal.org/project/tagorder

Comment: It's almost a bullseye! Thanks a lot Mary - this is slightly different from what I want, because this module looks at the tag order *per node*, but I want the order to change *everywhere*... nonetheless, I can just look at the code and see what needs to be done. And I *am* in Drupal 6!